# Android Web View Downloaded File "Can't Open File" Message

Tags: android, webview, android-download-manager

I have this below code for handling downloads in a Webview but when I try to open the file from downloads it says can't open file. If I go to a file manager app or appropriate app for open the downloaded file it opens without issue. can anyone shed some light on what is happening and how I can resolved this.

```
asw_view.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

            request.setMimeType("application/jpeg");
            //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            //request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: are you able to solve the issue. I am stuck with the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the mimetype, please check this link https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list .Second you setting mimetype two diferent way on the request `request.setMimeType("application/jpeg")` to `request.setMimeType(mimeType)` And  `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));`